# How do I output NUnit formatted xml with XUnit console?

Tags: xunit

I need NUnit output from XUnit tests for a report. With NUnit I can do:

```
nunit-console.exe /xml=c:\TestResultN.xml MyDll.dll
```

I've tried:

```
xunit.console MyDll.dll /nunit TestResults.xml
```

but I get:

```
unknown output transform: nunit
```

Any good docs on xunit console? I can't find any info.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Type `xunit.console.exe /?` in a console and look at the end of the option list.

```
> xunit.console.exe /?
xUnit.net console test runner (64-bit .NET 2.0.50727.4952)
Copyright (C) 2007-10 Microsoft Corporation.

usage: xunit.console <xunitProjectFile> [options]
usage: xunit.console <assemblyFile> [configFile] [options]

Valid options:
  /silent                : do not output running test count
  /teamcity              : forces TeamCity mode (normally auto-detected)
  /wait                  : wait for input after completion

Valid options for assemblies only:
  /noshadow              : do not shadow copy assemblies
  /xml <filename>        : output results to Xunit-style XML file
  /html <filename>       : output results to HTML file
  /nunit <filename>      : output results to NUnit-style XML file
```

The last two options are extracted from the config file and consist of a xslt file applied to the output of xunit. If `/nunit` is not present, make sure that you have the `NUnitXml.xslt` file in the xunit directory and the entry `nunit` is declared in the `xunit.console.exe.config` file.

My `xunit.console.exe.config` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="xunit" type="Xunit.ConsoleClient.XunitConsoleConfigurationSection, xunit.console"/>
  </configSections>

  <xunit>
    <transforms>
      <add
        commandline="html"
        xslfile="HTML.xslt"
        description="output results to HTML file"/>
      <add
        commandline="nunit"
        xslfile="NUnitXml.xslt"
        description="output results to NUnit-style XML file"/>
    </transforms>
  </xunit>

</configuration>
```

If you're not able to find theses files, you might need to reinstall xunit.

Answer (score 0):

First follow this link.
https://xunit.net/docs/getting-started/netfx/visual-studio

then open cmd from your main project folder as described in above link.
open file location of xunit.console.exe

run below command in cmd :

```
....\packages\xunit.runner.console.2.4.1\tools\net472\xunit.console.exe Project.UnitTests\bin\Debug\Project.UnitTests.dll -xml test_ouput.xml
```

Output result "test_ouput.xml" will be saved in project directory.